# Selecting multiple discontiguous cells throw exception 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Often in my code I need to define a range of multiple discontigous cells (thus I can't use colon `:` separator.

To select range I use `worksheet.Range[]`, even though in the internet I often see `get_Range()` method but it doesn't show up in the IntelliSense suggestions. I noticed no difference though when using `Range[]` or `get_Range()`.

The documentation says

> The name of the range. This must be an A1-style reference in the language of the macro. It can include the range operator (a colon), the intersection operator (a space), or the union operator (**a comma**). It can also include dollar signs, but they're ignored. You can use a local defined name in any part of the range. If you use a name, the name is assumed to be in the language of the macro.

So the union operator is comma according to the docs.

To make the picture clear I'll move straight to the examples.

This throws exception:

```
cell.Formula = "=SUM(A1;B5;C6)";
```

This works fine

```
cell.Formula = "=SUM(A1,B5,C6)";
```

This throws exception:

```
worksheet.Range["A1,B5,C6"];
```

This works fine

```
worksheet.Range["A1;B5;C6"];
```

It confuses me then which of those is actually correct so when to use commas and when semicolons.

Comment: This would not exactly be the first time in history that a programming language is inconsistent with regards to syntax across different functions. For instance, PHP is replete with such inconsistencies and the bottom line is that you just have to know the syntax for each function which makes programming harder and more cumbersome, but there is no easy way to get around this.

Comment: Why do you think semicolon will ever be valid?  `A1:D4` defines a rectangle with  A1 and D4 at the corners.  `A1` defines a single cell.  `A1:D4, E5, G6:H9` defines a union of three simple ranges.

Comment: I am assuming you are using the InterOp.  I have never used the InterOp from C# but from VB you must conform to Excel syntax within calls to Excel.

Comment: Excel syntax (the one that we use within the spreadsheet, not macros) is using `;` to union the cells (see for yourself by selecting cells while holding ctrl button), whilst when I define formula in the code I have to use `,`. Pradoxically when using pure code (`worksheet.Range[]`), I then use semicolons that are used in the Excel GUI formulas.

Comment: Instead of using `worksheet.Range["A1,B5,C6"]`, change it to `worksheet.Range("A1,B5,C6")` with parentheses instead of brackets. Whenever I type a formula into an excel cell and manually select discontinuous ranges, it uses a comma, not a semicolon. It would appear the documentation is correct: use commas. Why are you trying to force semi colons?

Comment: Strange. In my version of Excel, when I manually select ranges, it uses semicolons!

Comment: That's an internationalization behavior.  You can check the setting of the Excel instance with `app.International(xlListSeparator)` where `app` is your `Excel.Application` object.